# Proving that the $\lfloor-x\rfloor= -\lceil x\rceil$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> My homework assignment has asked me to prove that $\lfloor-x\rfloor = -\lceil x\rceil$.

Conceptually this makes perfect sense to me, I just am at a loss for how to start actually proving it. I figure that it has something to do with these definitions:
$$\lfloor x \rfloor: a \le x \lt a+1$$ $$ \lceil x \rceil : a \lt x \le a+1 $$

But I'm unsure of how to apply these to devise a proof for this. Any help that anyone could give would be incredibly appreciated, I've spent way too much time staring at the question trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{eqnarray}-x-1< &\lfloor -x \rfloor &\leq -x  \\
x\leq &\lceil x \rceil &< x+1 \end{eqnarray}

Adding these two we get $$(-x-1)+x<  \lfloor -x \rfloor + \lceil x \rceil <-x+(x+1)$$

$$-1< \lfloor -x \rfloor + \lceil x \rceil <1$$ so $$\lfloor -x \rfloor + \lceil x \rceil =0$$

Comment: Very nice proof!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$k\le -x<k+1\iff -k-1<x\le -k\\k\in\Bbb Z$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is an integer than an obvious equality holds. Otherwise we have $k-1\lt x\lt k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. So we have
$$\lfloor -x\rfloor=-k$$
$$-\lceil x \rceil = -k$$
which are equal. The first equality is true because $-k\lt-x\lt1-k$ so $\lfloor -x\rfloor$ takes the lower value. The second is true as $\lceil x \rceil$ takes the higher value and it becomes negated.

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand side says ($p_1=\lfloor{-x}\rfloor) \quad$    $-x=p_1+\varepsilon$ for some $0 \le \varepsilon \le 1$.

The right-hand side says ($p_2=-\lceil{x}\rceil)\quad $ $p_2=-(x+\delta)$ for some $0 \le \delta \le 1$.

Since both $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ are the distances from $-x$ to nearest integer less than $x$ they are equal and $p_1 = p_2$.

Answer (score 1):

With most elementary floor and ceiling proofs, the way to start is:  Let $x = k +r$ where $k$ is an integer and $0\leq r <1.$   That usually fixes everything.

You have, if $r\neq 0$:

$$\lfloor -x \rfloor = \lfloor -k-r \rfloor = -k +\lfloor -r \rfloor = -k -1.$$

and:

$$-\lceil x \rceil = -\lceil k+r \rceil = -(k+\lceil r \rceil)  = -k -1.$$

And if $r=0$, a similar thing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it:

We know that $\lfloor -x \rfloor \le -x < \lfloor -x \rfloor + 1$ and that $\lfloor -x \rfloor$ is an integer.

So $-\lfloor -x \rfloor \ge x > -\lfloor -x \rfloor-1$ and so $-\lfloor -x \rfloor- 1< x \le -\lfloor -x \rfloor$ and $-\lfloor -x \rfloor$ is an intger.

So by definition that means $\lceil x \rceil = -\lfloor -x \rfloor$.

And $\lfloor -x \rfloor = -\lceil x \rceil$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be given. By definition, $\lfloor -x \rfloor$ is the unique integer $a$ such that
$$
a \leq -x < a+1.
$$
Now, this implies that
$$
-(a+1) < x \leq -a
$$
where $-a \in \mathbb{Z}$ also. By definition of $\lceil x \rceil$, we must then have $\lceil x \rceil = -a$. In short, we have proven that
\begin{align*}
\lfloor -x \rfloor = a = -\lceil x \rceil.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The map $\varphi\colon x\mapsto -x$ is an order isomorphism of $(\mathbb{R},\le)$ onto $(\mathbb{R},\ge)$.

Since $\lfloor x\rfloor=\sup_{\le}\{z\in\mathbb{Z}:z\le x\}$ and $\varphi$ maps $\mathbb{Z}$ onto $\mathbb{Z}$, you're done, taking into account that $\lceil x\rceil=\sup_{\ge}\{z\in\mathbb{Z}:z\ge x\}$ and, obviously, $\sup_{\ge}$ is the same as $\inf_{\le}$.

Comment: Is $\lceil x \rceil$ a *supremum* or an *infimum*?

Comment: @mjw It's a supremum with respect to $\ge$ and an infimum with respect to $\le$.

Comment: I would have expected $\lceil x \rceil$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ to have dual descriptions.

Comment: @mjw They have: one is a supremum with respect to $\ge$, the other one is a supremum with respect to $\le$. Do you see the duality?

Comment: Yes, I would have thought, though, that $\lceil x\rceil=\inf_{\ge}\{z\in\mathbb{Z}:z\ge x\}$.

Comment: @mjw $\inf_{\ge}=\sup_{\le}$.

Comment: Yes, that is fine.  Please look again at your expressions for $\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $\lceil x \rceil$.  I believe you have a proof.  I just think there possibly may be a typo in the second expression.

Comment: @mjw No, there isn't. Don't be fooled by the unusual use of symbols.

Comment: What exactly does $\sup_{\ge}$ mean?

Comment: @mjw The supremum with respect to the order relation $\ge$ (which is not the same as $\le$, but its opposite)

Comment: This is a *supremum* over integers greater than $x$, or an *infimum* over integers greater than $x$?  Asking about $\lceil x \rceil$.