# Proof that $\left\lfloor -x\right\rfloor =-\left\lceil x\right\rceil$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I wanted to ask if this kind of reasoning for proving the result in the title could be considered correct:

We know that: $\left\lceil x\right\rceil =n$ if and only if $n-1<x\leq n$

Then $-\left\lceil x\right\rceil =-n $ if and only if $-n-1<x\leq-n$

Then multiplying by $-1$ the formula $-n-1<x\leq-n$ we get $n+1>-x\geq n$ , inverting the sign.

But $n+1>-x\geq n$ is equivalent to $n\leq-x<n+1$.

We know that $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor  = n$ if and only if $ n\leq x<n+1$.

So from $n\leq-x<n+1$ we can infer that $\left\lfloor -x\right\rfloor =$ $n=-\left\lceil x\right\rceil$

Comment: Looks correct. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3163742/42969.

Comment: I think you have a couple of errors that cancel out in the end. For instance $f(x)=n\iff something$ is equivalent to $-f(x)=-y\iff something$. So when you change signs the first time to $-\lceil x\rceil=-n$ you should not also change the condition to something NOT equivalent. The condition $-n-1<x\leq -n$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

From the definitions,
$$\lfloor x\rfloor=-n\iff -n-1<x\le-n$$
and
$$\lfloor-x\rfloor=n\iff n\le-x<n+1.$$

These are equivalent statements.

---

Alternatively, WLOG the integer part is $0$ (because the floor/ceiling commute with addition of an integer), and the fractional part is $0$ or $\in (0,1)$, say $0.5$.

We have
$$\lfloor-0\rfloor=-0=-\lceil-0\rceil$$

and

$$\lfloor-0.5\rfloor=-1=-\lceil-0.5\rceil.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is quite involved, I think. Try to use the definitions of floor and ceiling directly instead.

By definition, $\lfloor y \rfloor = k$ if $k$ is the greatest integer such that $k \leq y$, and $\lceil y \rceil = k$ if $k$ is the least integer such that $y \leq k$. Moreover, we know that $x_1 \leq x_2$ if and only if $-x_2 < -x_1$.

So if $\lfloor -x \rfloor = k$, then $k \leq -x$ and therefore $x \leq -k$. Moreover, $-k$ must be the least such integer, since $k$ is the greatest integer such that $k \leq -x$.

Answer (score 0):

Go straight at it, but make careful and clear steps:
$$
\begin{align}
\lfloor -x\rfloor =n
&\iff n\leq -x<n+1\\
&\iff -n\geq x>-n-1
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
-\lceil x\rceil=n&\iff \lceil x\rceil=-n\\
&\iff -n-1 < x \leq -n
\end{align}
$$